# Rewrite adressing location from HTTPS to HTTP

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url-rewriting, .net-core, middleware

Is it possible to rewrite addressing location from https to http? I'm trying several ways to implement this, but it's always opening the page with https.

I tried to add these rules to `app.Use`:

```
    app.Use(async (context, next) =>
    {
        if (context.Request.IsHttps)
        {
            if (context.Request.Path.Value.Contains("https") && !context.Request.Path.Value.Contains(".salesrater.com"))
            {
                var path = context.Request.Path.Value.Replace("https", "http");
                context.Response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = path;
                context.Response.Redirect(path);
            }
            else
            {
                await next();
            }
        }
    });
```

This case isn't working for me. I then tried to use the Rewrite option:

```
    var options = new RewriteOptions();
    options.Add(new ServerRewriteRule(cache, Configuration));
    app.UseRewriter(options);
```

Which is implemented in the class like this:

```
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    var path = $"{request.Scheme}://{mapping.Domain}{request.Path.Value.Replace(mapping.Path, string.Empty)}{request.QueryString}";

    if (path.Contains("https"))
    {
        path = path.Replace("https", "http");
    }

    var response = context.HttpContext.Response;
    response.StatusCode = StatusCodes.Status302Found;
    response.Headers[HeaderNames.Location] = path;
    response.Redirect(path);
    context.Result = RuleResult.EndResponse;
```

**Update:** I forgot to note that I've got cases where I need to filter some URLs, which should go to https and which should not

Comment: You tell it to `context.Response.Redirect(context.Request.Path.Value);` in the first case, of course it goes back to HTTPS :) You'll need to use the full URI also, the path does not contain the scheme (HTTPS).

Comment: @juunas, yeah, didn't notice this, just updated this post and also didn't work for me, it still running website with https and not redirecting to http :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do that in web.config, no need to do that from code. Use rewrite rule: 
[https://forums.iis.net/t/1206943.aspx?HTTPS+to+HTTP+redirect+in+web+config](https://forums.iis.net/t/1206943.aspx?HTTPS%20to%20HTTP%20redirect%20in%20web%20config)

```
<rule name="Redirect to HTTP" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions>
    <add input="{R:1}" pattern="^onepage/(.*)$" negate="true" />
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^ON$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="http://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" redirectType="Permanent" />
</rule>
```

Comment: @Vitaliy Yes, it should.

Comment: I updated my post, sorry that didn't noticed before, so I've case where I need to filter some url, which should go to https and which should not go to https

Comment: @Vitaliy So in that case you can set multiple rules and play around with: <match url="(.*)" />

Comment: Should I hardcode them? Or somehow I can modify them from code, because all custom domain are store in db. I guess I need regex to implement this, because in my case only subdomain allowed to use https

Comment: @Vitaliy Since web.config is XML file, you shoul be able to create and modify rules from code. But it needs some digging around. Or yes, you can hardcode them. Otherwise, what is wrong with HTTPS? so you need to use HTTP?

Comment: Your variant is work correctly, but now I can't access to subdomain, I'm trying to get rule, which if user accessing to website with subdomain, he able to use ssl, but if he accessing to website with www.domainname.com it will permanently redirect to http

Comment: Why I'm doing this, because I've an issue with facebook, if user post some material from my application which before he have access only to subdomain and when he grant a custom domain and open a post from a facebook (it store an old url and automaticcaly on click redirects to his custom url), it block, facebook doesn't want to display a page without ssl. So i thought this may be a solution to fix this